# How this method is called?

Tags: delphi

Coding in Delphi book has this example about interface constraint :

```
1    type
2      IStoppable  =  interface
3        procedure Stop;
4      end;
5
6      TWidget<T: IStoppable>  =  class
7        FProcess: T;
8        procedure StopProcess;
9      end;
10
11   { TWidget<T> }
12
13   procedure  TWidget<T>.StopProcess;
14   begin
15     FProcess.Stop;
16   end;
```

I don't understand in line 15 how he call the "Stop" method?? isn't FProcess is a generic variable? So how can he call a method from a variable?

Also how can he call the "Stop" method directly from an interface? Isn't it supposed to call the implemented method?

Comment: Since T is declared as IStoppable, he is calling IStoppable.Stop. That looks fine (except the weird formatting).

Comment: many thanks I want to hug you all :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FProcess` is of type `T` where `T` is constrained to be an interface that is `IStoppable` or one derived from `IStoppable`. The method call you refer to therefore calls the `Stop` method of `IStoppable`.

Imagine instead that `FProcess` was declared to be of type `IStoppable`.

```
FProcess: IStoppable;
```

If that were so then I think you would understand the code.

Whenever you find yourself struggling to understand generic code this is a useful technique. Replace the generic type with a concrete type and read the code again. It is often much easier to understand concrete code and that understanding will then help you generalise to the generic code.

As far as where the method is implemented that is no different here as for a concrete interface. An interface defines the interface but leaves the implementation unspecified. The class that implements the interfaces specifies that but you don't need to know about that in order to use an interface. That's really the modus operandi for interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

`FProcess` is declared as generic type `T`, but that is declared, in the constraint, as `IStoppable`, in other words: every `T` must be an `IStoppable` (or derivate) and the code can be sure that it can call the methods of `IStoppable` on it

It is perfectly fine to call a method on an interface. That is the main reason they exist: they are basically a list of methods that can be called.

And yes, the method must be implemented somewhere. That is not shown.